# Azure SDK for .NET authentication - where to keep the generated service principal?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk-.net, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to understand how to authenticate with Azure during development and production.

For development I followed the instructions here: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-sdk-azure-get-started?view=azure-dotnet#set-up-authentication)

I now have a file and an environment variable that the Azure SDK uses for authentication.

However for production I don't know where to put this file. In this case, production is itself a set of Azure Functions which uses the Azure SDK. In the documentation the service principal is stored on `C:\`.

Should I forgo the environment variable and instead place the service principal file in my `src` directory (and exclude it from commits of course) and then make sure the file is copied to the output so that it is present for both development and production?

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
        .FromFile("service-principle.json"); // same dir as the Azure Function DLLs
```

Comment: I think you should put this settings in the app settings. in dev it will be in the `local.settings.json` file. Once deployed on Azure, you can put these set these settings from the function app settings blade on the azure portal

Comment: That could work, but what about making sure it doesn't get committed? There's other settings in there. Can you have more than one settings.json?

Comment: You can just ignore this file (.gitignore) from source control. you can have as many settings as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas mentioned that you could add the setting in the Azure function appsetting in the Azure portal.

Then you could use the following command get the credentials. How to use azure function appsettings, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings).

Note: Need to save the setting after add them. Then we could use  `SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, environment: AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);` to get the credentials.

Following is the demo code.

```
var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("clientId");
var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("clientSecret");
var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("tenantId");
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, environment: AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
```

It is not recommended to publish the Credentials file to azure function, if you still want to do that. You could use the Azure function kudu tool. And Azure function D:\home is shared, you could upload your service-principle.json to the folder you want.

Comment: Is `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("clientId")` already set by Azure or will I need to do that?

Comment: No, you need to add it to azure function appsetting on the azure portal.

Comment: I also recommand that you could use [Azure function MSI feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity), it is no need to keep the clientId,clientSecret,tenantId information for the app.